# Wants to convert the "choice" column to "managed metadata" column in SharePoint 2010

Tags: managed-metadata, choice-field

I have a "choice" (Checkboxes (allow multiple selections) ) column and wanted to convert the column as "managed metadata" column without any data loss. 
Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the managed metadata Field -> Multivalue (allow multivalue)

```
○ Create a local term group, set, terms, term
○ Ref - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/75ae3a89-7d28-41d9-b58c-56d4f7e9771d

$site = Get-SPSite "SiteURL"
$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
$web = $site.openWeb() ;
$termStore = $session.TermStores["Enterprise Metadata Service Proxy"];
$group = $termStore.Groups["GroupName"];
$termSet = $group.TermSets["TermSet"];
$terms = $termSet.Terms;

$list = $web.Lists["ListName"];

$list.Items |% {

$spItem = $_;

write-host "Updating the Item - $($_.Id)";

#Get the taxonomy field for the list item
$taxField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spItem.Fields["TaxField"]

#Create a term collection
$termCollection = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection($taxField);

$termName = $spItem["ChoiceField"].ToString() -replace ";#",",";

foreach($indTerm in $termName.Split(","))
{   
    if($indTerm.Length -gt 0)
    {
    #Get each individual term.
    $term = $terms | where {$_.Name -eq $indTerm}

    #Creating a field value that represents one term
    $taxonomyFieldValue = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue($taxField)
    $taxonomyFieldValue.TermGuid = $term.Id
    $taxonomyFieldValue.Label = $term.Name  

    #Add term to collection.
    $termCollection.Add($taxonomyFieldValue)
    }
}

#Adding the Term Collection to the column.  
$taxField.SetFieldValue($spItem, $termCollection);
$spItem.SystemUpdate();

}

$web.Close();
$site.Dispose();
```

Comment: I think you misinterpret the question. The OP wants to convert a SPChoiceField to a SPTaxonomyField, not change an existing TaxonomyField from simple to multiple valued

Answer (score 2):

From my experience this will have to be done programmatically.
Add a new managed metadata column manually then write a console app or PowerShell to loop trhough the items/documents and match the selected value with the managed metadata equivalent. Then do a SystemUpdate(false) on the item (the false part will preventing the version from being increased)

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there any script readily available?